# UI becomes very slow to show tooltips when loading massive amount of data

Tags: wpf, charts, telerik, tooltip

I am now using Telerik UI for WPF RadCartesianChart's LineSeries to show tooltip. But when loading massive amount of data about 18866 records, UI becomes too slow to show tooltips and finally becomes freeze. Could someone please help me how to solve this issue? Thanks a lot.

This is *View/TabView.xaml*

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart x:Name="RotGraph"
                                    MinHeight="325"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Panel.ZIndex="5"
                                    MouseDown="RotGraph_MouseDown"
                                    TouchDown="RotGraph_TouchDown">

                                    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>
                                        <telerik:ChartTooltipBehavior HorizontalOffset="-11" VerticalOffset="-50"/>
                                    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>

                                    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.TooltipTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5" CornerRadius="3">
                                                    <StackPanel>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataItem.LegendName}"/>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataItem.ToolTipDate}"/>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataItem.ToolTipValue}"/>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </StackPanel> 
                                                </Border>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.TooltipTemplate>

                                    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                                        <telerik:DateTimeCategoricalAxis HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            LabelFormat="MMMdd"
                                            LabelInterval="1"
                                            LabelStyle="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}"
                                            LastLabelVisibility="Visible"
                                            LineStroke="{DynamicResource CouleurTexte}"
                                            LineThickness="1"
                                            utilities:ChartUtilities.MajorTickInterval= "{Binding Tab.MajorTickInterval}"
                                            LabelFitMode="Rotate"
                                            MajorTickLength="5"
                                            MajorTickOffset="0"
                                            PlotMode="OnTicks"
                                            SmartLabelsMode="SmartStep"
                                            TickThickness="3"
                                            ZIndex="0" />
                                    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>

                                    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                                        <telerik:LinearAxis Title="(tons/day)"
                                            LabelInterval="1"
                                            LabelStyle="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                                            LineStroke="{DynamicResource CouleurTexte}"
                                            LineThickness="1"
                                            MajorStep="1"                                          
                                            SmartLabelsMode="SmartStep"                                                          
                                            TickThickness="1" />                                                                                                                    
                                    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>

                                    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Resources>
                                        <telerik:LinearAxis x:Key="AxisR"
                                            Title="(deg)"
                                            HorizontalLocation="Right"
                                            LabelInterval="1"
                                            LabelStyle="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}"
                                            LineStroke="#FFCE8819"                                          
                                            SmartLabelsMode="SmartStep" />

                                    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Resources>

                                    <telerik:LineSeries x:Name="rollstt"
                                        CategoryBinding="TimeStampX"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Tab.RollGraph}"
                                        Stroke="White"
                                        ValueBinding="ValueY"
                                        VerticalAxis="{StaticResource AxisR}"
                                        Visibility="{Binding Tab.IsRollSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">

                                        <telerik:LineSeries.LegendSettings>
                                            <telerik:SeriesLegendSettings Title="Roll (deg)" />
                                        </telerik:LineSeries.LegendSettings>
                                        <telerik:LineSeries.DefaultVisualStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="Path">
                                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="4" />
                                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="4" />
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </telerik:LineSeries.DefaultVisualStyle>                                       

                                    </telerik:LineSeries>

                                    <telerik:LineSeries x:Name="pitchstt"
                                        CategoryBinding="TimeStampX"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Tab.PitchGraph}"
                                        Stroke="#FFF19400"
                                        ValueBinding="ValueY"
                                        VerticalAxis="{StaticResource AxisR}"
                                        Visibility="{Binding Tab.IsPitchSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                        <telerik:LineSeries.LegendSettings>
                                            <telerik:SeriesLegendSettings Title="Pitch (deg)" />
                                        </telerik:LineSeries.LegendSettings>
                                        <telerik:LineSeries.DefaultVisualStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="Path">
                                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="4" />
                                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="4" />
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFF19400" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </telerik:LineSeries.DefaultVisualStyle>
                                    </telerik:LineSeries>

                                    <telerik:LineSeries x:Name="natbog1"
                                        CategoryBinding="TimeStampX"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Tab.NBOGStats}"
                                        Stroke="#FF08A1EE"
                                        ValueBinding="ValueY">
                                        <telerik:LineSeries.LegendSettings>
                                            <telerik:SeriesLegendSettings Title="Natural Bog (tons/day)" />
                                        </telerik:LineSeries.LegendSettings>
                                        <telerik:LineSeries.DefaultVisualStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="Path">
                                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="4" />
                                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="4" />
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF08A1EE" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </telerik:LineSeries.DefaultVisualStyle>
                                    </telerik:LineSeries>

                                </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
```

This is *model/ShipMotionStat.cs*

```
public void SetValueGraphDatafromSQL(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
    {
        try
        {
            var pitch = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();
            var roll = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();
            var sway = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();
            var surge = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();
            var heave = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();
            var yaw = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();

            //gets all the current values in a collection where each timestamp has corresponding values
            IEnumerable<ExchangeFile.TimeValue> stats = AllDBdatas.Where(a => a.TimeStamp >= StartDate && a.TimeStamp <= EndDate).OrderBy(c => c.TimeStamp);

            //Create graph values for motion Stat
            foreach (ExchangeFile.TimeValue item in stats)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Data creation for pitch graphs
                    pitch.Add(new ChartData()
                    {
                        TimeStampX = item.TimeStamp,
                        ValueY = item.Value[PitchPostion],
                        LegendName = "Pitch",
                        ToolTipDate = item.TimeStamp.ToString(),
                        ToolTipValue = item.Value[PitchPostion].ToString("F") + " deg"

                    });
                    //Data creation for roll graphs
                    roll.Add(new ChartData()
                    {
                        TimeStampX = item.TimeStamp,
                        ValueY = item.Value[RollPosition],
                        LegendName = "Roll",
                        ToolTipDate = item.TimeStamp.ToString(),
                        ToolTipValue = item.Value[RollPosition].ToString("F") + " deg"
                    });
                    sway.Add(new ChartData()
                    {
                        TimeStampX = item.TimeStamp,
                        ValueY = item.Value[SwayPosition],
                        LegendName = "Sway",
                        ToolTipDate = item.TimeStamp.ToString(),
                        ToolTipValue = item.Value[SwayPosition].ToString("F") + " m"
                    });
                    surge.Add(new ChartData()
                    {
                        TimeStampX = item.TimeStamp,
                        ValueY = item.Value[SurgePosition],
                        LegendName = "Surge",
                        ToolTipDate = item.TimeStamp.ToString(),
                        ToolTipValue = item.Value[SurgePosition].ToString("F") + " m"
                    });
                    heave.Add(new ChartData()
                    {
                        TimeStampX = item.TimeStamp,
                        ValueY = item.Value[HeavePostion],
                        LegendName = "Heave",
                        ToolTipDate = item.TimeStamp.ToString(),
                        ToolTipValue = item.Value[HeavePostion].ToString("F") + " m"
                    });
                    yaw.Add(new ChartData()
                    {
                        TimeStampX = item.TimeStamp,
                        ValueY = item.Value[YawPosition],
                        LegendName = "Yaw",
                        ToolTipDate = item.TimeStamp.ToString(),
                        ToolTipValue = item.Value[YawPosition].ToString("F") + " m"
                    });


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    statLog.AddLog(e);
                    //Continue loop even exception occured, Sometimes the Dataset will have issue based on the latency of the Server
                    continue;
                }
            }


            if (NatboTotal != null)
            {
                NaturalBOG = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>(NatboTotal.Where(a => a.TimeStampX >= StartDate && a.TimeStampX <= EndDate));
            }
            else
            {
                NaturalBOG = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();
            }
            RollGraph = roll;
            PitchGraph = pitch;
            HeaveGraph = heave;
            SurgeGraph = surge;
            SwayGraph = sway;
            YawGraph = yaw;             

            //Inform the main model that Graph data are updated
            Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage("MotionsStatsUpdated"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            statLog.AddLog(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are absolutely convinced, that it is reasonable to read and handle more than 18k data records from the database at once, then at least do it asynchronously or in a separate thread (using `Task`). You are obviously starving the UI, by occupying all its resources, which leads to an unresponsive UI.

Comment: Thanks, I will try as per your suggestion.